# Intermittent AWS Issue CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

getting the below issue from CloudFront intermittently:

"CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection."

while access from one region(eg: US) it is working fine but while access from another region getting this issue  intermittently

Any specific reason due to different region?

Comment: Does this happens to a private S3 bucket?

Comment: public S3 bucket